# How to debug memory leaks on Linux

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I've noticed that both on chrome and firefox, if I leave the browser on (regardless of where it points to) the memory consumed by those processes continually increases, e.g. as seen below for chrome where it reaches several GB.

```
2999231 user   20   0   28.6g 276656 101584 S   0.7   1.7   0:15.08 chrome                                            
2999384 user   20   0  235712   4988   4120 R   0.7   0.0   0:00.67 top                                               
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0  22:07.21 rcu_preempt                                       
    932 systemd+  20   0   17580   3696   3336 S   0.3   0.0  45:57.00 systemd-oomd                                      
   1098 root      20   0  555752  11600   9484 S   0.3   0.1  18:02.35 NetworkManager                                    
1748218 user   20   0  844952  33588  20936 S   0.3   0.2   2:01.62 gnome-terminal-                                   
2988161 user   20   0   16.8g 260840 171468 S   0.3   1.6   2:19.84 chrome                                            
2988615 user   20   0   16.5g 107820  84448 S   0.3   0.7   1:33.54 chrome                                            
2988876 user   20   0   24.6g  90228  71268 S   0.3   0.6   0:53.98 chrome                                            
      1 root      20   0  177644  10048   5872 S   0.0   0.1   1:37.62 systemd
```

The output of ldd is shown below. How does one determine the culprit in this case. Given that the issue happens on both chrome and firefox I suspect it has to do with shared libs vs. a common bug in the implementation.

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1fdc7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc92dd43000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc92dd22000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92dcc7000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92db8d000)
    libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007fc92da4f000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fc92da1c000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007fc92d9ee000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007fc92d9ab000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92d982000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92d949000)
    libcups.so.2 => /lib64/libcups.so.2 (0x00007fc92d8aa000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92d6d6000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fc92d6be000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fc92d66c000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fc92d63b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc92d4f7000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fc92d3af000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fc92d3aa000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fc92d3a3000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fc92d38e000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fc92d385000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fc92d378000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /lib64/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007fc92d367000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fc92d33c000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib64/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fc92d2f1000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92d29d000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fc92d181000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib64/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fc92d074000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib64/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007fc92d037000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc92d01c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc92ce4b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc939269000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fc92ce40000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fc92cdc8000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007fc92cdc1000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007fc92cdbc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc92cdaf000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fc92cd58000)
    libavahi-common.so.3 => /lib64/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007fc92cd49000)
    libavahi-client.so.3 => /lib64/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007fc92cd34000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib64/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fc92cb25000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc92cb0b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc92cb03000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fc92cac0000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fc92ca94000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fc92ca7a000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib64/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fc92c9b6000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fc92c9a7000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /lib64/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007fc92c991000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fc92c98b000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib64/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007fc92c96d000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib64/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fc92c962000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fc92c892000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fc92c7e4000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fc92c795000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fc92c6d1000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fc92c698000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fc92c693000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fc92c683000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fc92c66f000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fc92c591000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fc92c579000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fc92c572000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fc92c561000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fc92c55a000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fc92c26a000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib64/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fc92c138000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib64/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fc92c117000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib64/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fc92bf93000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib64/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fc92bf7b000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib64/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007fc92bf31000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib64/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007fc92beec000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fc92be4a000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fc92be15000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fc92bd7e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fc92bd52000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib64/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fc92bca1000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib64/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fc92bc7d000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fc92bc73000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fc92bb37000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib64/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fc92bb2e000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fc92bb0d000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fc92b982000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fc92b96f000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007fc92b961000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fc92b93b000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007fc92b916000)
```

I tried `valgrind` but the output is not super useful at this point

```
3003038:3003038:0100/000000.824434:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.

[vvarada@localhost ~]$ valgrind /opt/google/chrome/chrome 
==3003130== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3003130== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3003130== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3003130== Command: /opt/google/chrome/chrome
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39F078F: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F02D9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0095: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFC4E: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBC9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe2fc060 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x30223DD: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F074C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F02D9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0095: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFC4E: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBC9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 

....
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x2C84DD6: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0808: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F02D9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0095: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFC4E: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBC9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe2fc2b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) 


==3003130==    by 0x2923723: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AD0: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149B3: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x3914A8C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149B3: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300ce0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x22B2527: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x29236A9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914A71: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149B3: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AA2: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149B3: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300db0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 64 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x22B2527: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x29236A9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AD0: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149B3: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x2641769: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x2923695: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AD0: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300f00 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x2923723: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AD0: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x3914A8C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300ea0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x2923723: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914A71: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AA2: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300f60 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 64 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x2641700: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x2923695: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3914AD0: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149E4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39149EC: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe300e30 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x22B2527: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x29236A9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149D6: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F03E7: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39149EC: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F045B: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe3010b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x22B2527: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x29236A9: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39149D6: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x391484C: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F045B: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFBD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF98A: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0CD4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFF74: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe301260 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFE82: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0A65: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFF74: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe3013e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x2F8CE51: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0A30: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFF74: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFFA1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe3012c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFFD1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3003130==    at 0xBE4D2BB: cfree (vg_replace_malloc.c:898)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFFB6: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130==  Address 0xe301320 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3003130==    at 0xBE4C22F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:640)
==3003130==    by 0x30223DD: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EFF53: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9C6: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== 
==3003130== Process terminating with default action of signal 5 (SIGTRAP): dumping core
==3003130==    at 0x5143FD4: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3BB37FF: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3FEF1A1: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x3FEED3A: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39F0146: ??? (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0x39EF9E3: ChromeMain (in /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
==3003130==    by 0xCBCEB74: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.33.so)
==3003130== 
==3003130== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3003130==     in use at exit: 149,060 bytes in 972 blocks
==3003130==   total heap usage: 1,700 allocs, 728 frees, 197,108 bytes allocated
==3003130== 
==3003130== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3003130==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3003130==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3003130==      possibly lost: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==3003130==    still reachable: 142,948 bytes in 950 blocks
==3003130==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3003130== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3003130== 
==3003130== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3003130== ERROR SUMMARY: 66 errors from 42 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Valgrind really needs to be used with programs compiled with debugging info in order to be useful.